# How to implement event listenner on google map ClusterManager?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using `GoogleMaps` marker clustering available in the utils library. On clicking a `Cluster`, the below `onClusterClick()` and `onClusterItemClick()` method is not called. Is there a Cluster click event?

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    /*start clustring*/

    clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getActivity(), map);
    map.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);

    /*end clustring*/



    LatLng karawanbazar1 = new LatLng(36.861666, 10.156551);
    LatLng karawanbazar2 = new LatLng(36.860179, 10.152874);



    MyItemMap myItemMap1 = new MyItemMap(karawanbazar1);
    MyItemMap myItemMap2 = new MyItemMap(karawanbazar2);


    clusterManager.addItem(myItemMap1);

    clusterManager.addItem(myItemMap2);


    clusterManager.cluster();
    clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItemMap>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItemMap myItemMap) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"onclusterItemClick"+ myItemMap.getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            System.out.println("this is cluster clusteItemClick "+myItemMap.toString() );
            return true;
        }
    });
    clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItemMap>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItemMap> cluster) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"setOnClusterClickListener"+ cluster.getSize(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            System.out.println("this is cluster onClusterClick "+cluster.toString() );

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Copy all of your activity/fragment code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i had to do is to add this line before using events on clusters.

```
  map.setOnMarkerClickListener(yourClusterManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

Propably what you are looking for is a method `setOnMarkerClickListener()` of `GoogleMap` object:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager)
```

Then you have to set:

```
clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener()
```

Comment: sorry but you need to set OnMarkerClickListener not onMapClickListener

Comment: You asked how to add event listener to ClusterManager with GoogleMap and that is what this answer provided.

Comment: onMapClickListener doesn t accept a clusterManager as a parameter

Comment: My bad, i worte correct method name in info and copied wrong one to code brackets

Comment: it's ok. We are her to help each other :P